# How can I find albums with "readable": false field via API?

Tags: deezer

How can I find albums with "readable": false field via API? For example, there is an album from one artist that already in Deezer database but it have ("readable": false) field, how can I find it via API without direct link?

Comment: What do you mean find it ? Besides albums themselves don't have a readable field, only tracks can have readable set to true or false

Comment: Maybe you mean the field "available"?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the following album available:false without alternative : 
http://api.deezer.com/album/745497

and the following one available:false with an alternative album available somewhere else in the catalogue : 
http://api.deezer.com/album/44097

Comment: Please post here relevant part of thoses links that does answer the question, remembering a link can go broken and / or outdated